# How to use the filter function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

am trying to use the filter function to determine the number of survey participants in excel between the ages of 20 and 35, but I can't seem to figure this out. I tried this

```
=FILTER(A2:E360,(D2:D360>=18)*(D2:D360<=25))
```

but i did not get the result i was hoping for. What is the proper syntax for this problem?

Comment: Please use proper tags, are you using `Excel` or `GS`, though both alike but there is lot of difference. Next your formula doesn't seems anything wrong, hence it shall be better if you update the query with a TEXTUAL Data so that someone can copy it easily to create a formula

Comment: If you trying to get the number of participants, then why not just countifs?

Comment: @JvdV Sir, may be the range of values where the ages falls between. But going forward OP needs to confirm whether they are using Excel or GS.

Comment: my apologies, I'm using excel. I should have been more specific.

Comment: There is no issues with your formula unless the range `D2:D360` is formatted as text. Perhaps this is my assumption, i will still request you to share a sample of your data to visualise and transparency of your query

Answer (score 0):

in GS (based on your tag) it goes like this:

```
=FILTER(A2:E360; D2:D360>=18; D2:D360<=25)
```

Comment: Thank you! based on this function =FILTER(A2:D360,(D2:D360>=18)*(D2:D360<26),"none") it's returning #SPILL! any reason why this might be happening?